# React Router Dom Protected Route Always Redirects to Login during refresh page

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I’m building a full stack react application. I have implement React router v4 protected route. everything going good but the problem is that after user login on refresh link it redirect to login page.

### Here is the auth.js code: it is use for check authentication during login and logout time.

```
class Auth {
  constructor() {
    this.authenticated = false;
  }

  login(cb) {
    this.authenticated = true;
    cb();
    console.log("login status"+this.authenticated)
  }

  logout(cb) {
    this.authenticated = false;
    cb();
  }

  isAuthenticated() {
    console.log("check status"+this.authenticated)
    return this.authenticated;
  }
}
export default new Auth();
```

### Here is ProtectedRoute.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect,withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Auth from "./Auth";

const ProtectedRoute = ({component: Component,...rest}) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props => {
        if (Auth.isAuthenticated()) {
          return <Component {...props} />;
        } else {
          return (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: "/admin/login",
                state: {
                  from: props.location
                }
              }}
            />
          );
        }
      }}
    />
  );
};
export default withRouter(ProtectedRoute);
```

### Here is app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import './css/style.css'
import './css/font-awesome.css'
import './css/jquery-ui.css'
import './App.css';
import './css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap'
import 'jquery'
import Login from './components/Login';
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard'
import Users from './components/Users'
import UserProfile from './components/UserProfile';
import Categories from './components/Categories'
import ContactUs from './components/ContactUs'
import QueryDetails from './components/QueryDetails'
import EditProfile from './components/EditProfile'
import AdminProfile from './components/AdminProfile'
import ChangePassword from './components/ChangePassword'
import SaleOrPurchaseList from './components/SaleOrPurchaseList'
import ProductDetails from './components/ProductDetails'
import ReportList from './components/ReportList'
import NotFound from './components/NotFound'
import ProtectedRoute  from './components/ProtectedRoute';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/admin/login" component={Login}/>
        <ProtectedRoute path='/admin/dashboard' component={Dashboard}/>
        <ProtectedRoute path='/admin/users' component={Users}/>
        <ProtectedRoute path='/admin/userProfile' component={UserProfile}/>
        <ProtectedRoute path='/admin/saleOrPurchaseList' component={SaleOrPurchaseList}/>
        <ProtectedRoute path='/admin/ProductDetails' component={ProductDetails}/>
        <ProtectedRoute path='/admin/categories' component={Categories}/>
        <ProtectedRoute path='/admin/reportList' component={ReportList}/>  
        <ProtectedRoute path='/admin/queries' component={ContactUs}/>
        <ProtectedRoute path='/admin/query_details' component={QueryDetails}/>
        <ProtectedRoute path='/admin/profile' component={AdminProfile}/>
        <ProtectedRoute path='/admin/edit_profile' component={EditProfile}/>
        <ProtectedRoute path='/admin/change_password' component={ChangePassword}/>
        <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter> 
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You can use `localStorage` to save the state of the authentication, `localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', this.state.authenticated)` . In localStorage, it'll be maintained even in new window tabs and you have to manually remove it on logout.

Comment: Like in value of `login` function you can set the value of auth state like this `localStorage.setItem('isAuth', this.authenticated)`. In logout function `localStorage.removeItem('isAuth')` .

Comment: ok i am doing it right now

Comment: https://pastebin.com/8940A2Mb And for Privateroute file you can refer this

Comment: I think setting true false value won't be a good approach, better store a variable and on logout remove that variable from localStorage

Comment: I set  localStorage.setItem('isAuth', true) during login & localStorage.removeItem('isAuth') during logout and then Privateroute link as you send above and now it works for me Thank you very much

Comment: I added all that as an answer so you can accept it and mark your question as answered.

Comment: Done & Thanks Buddy

Comment: No problem man, it's like a practice for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `localStorage` in order to handle the Authentication.
In login function you can set the value of auth state like this localStorage.setItem('isAuth', authenticated). In logout function `localStorage.removeItem('isAuth')`. Change the PrivateRoute as per the `localStorage`

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateRoute = ({
    component: Component,
    ...rest
}) => {
    const isAuth = localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn');
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={props =>
                isAuth ? (
                    <Component {...props} {...rest} />
                ) : (
                        <Redirect
                            to={{
                                pathname: "/admin/login",
                                state: {
                                  from: props.location
                                }
                            }}
                        />
                    )
                }
        />
    );
}

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.authenticated` is `false` by default so whenever `ProtectedRoute` renders before call to `Auth.login` it will redirect to login page. You need to ensure that `this.authenticated` gets the correct value before rendering `ProtectedRoute`.

Note that it is very likely that your code doesn't trigger a rerender of `ProtectedRoute` after call to `Auth.login` or `Auth.logout`. So `ProtectedRoute` won't react to `this.authenticated` changes.

Comment: is there a way to solve this. I currently have the same problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61991574/react-routes-protected-routes-always-redirecting