# how to clear localStorage on browser window close not on tab close and not on Refresh in React JS?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

I am using `react-router-dom`  with `Switch`, `Route`, `withRouter` . How to implement in this scenario in React js. 
Basically i used `window.onbeforeunload` but this is wokring on tab close but this is not my scenario. I want on browser window close not on tab close and not on Refresh clear the `localStorage`.

Comment: not able to understand what you want

Comment: 1)Open browser and login into my application .
2)on right click side bar of application, open new tab-> application will be open.
The Question is-> if i close the browser's  then my application should not be logged out My localStorage not clear that time.

Comment: Then in that case you can use localstorage to store the token

Comment: we are using authToken

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55257505/8437974, I think you can store the token in a variable and with that check in <ProtectedRoute />

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps instead of using localStorage you could use sessionStorage? This lasts for as long as the tab is open rather than the page (browser). A good link to view regarding this can be found at [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/localstorage) and highlights the subtle differences between the two.

Comment: If i user session Storage instead of LocalStorge then how i will communicate in two tab? Means If i right click on the side bar of application and open a new tab or window then my application will not be open . Thats why i am using localStorage

Comment: Well that's a different kettle of fish, not mentioned in your question. You're probably going to have to work with database storage if thats what you want, or of course, live with the limitations of localStorage.