# I have to login again after page refresh. React-router-dom authentication issue

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router, react-router-dom

I implemented authentication the same way as it is recommended [here](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow) by react-router-dom developers. It works fine. But there is a problem. I have to login again after page refresh. How to fix that? Any workaround is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Do you use any session information? Maybe you can use session token to consider login time whether expired or not.

Additionaly, could you please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240578/react-router-dom-protected-route-always-redirects-to-login-during-refresh-page)?

(Can not add as comment, because of the reputation.)